# Order a varchar column numerically in ascending order

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am trying to arrange data in a column(type varchar, name=PRODUCTVERSION) of an ORACLE SQL TABLE in ascending order.
I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM KCProductVersion where productid =1 ORDER BY PRODUCTVERSION asc
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could split the version number into individual numbers and order by that:

```
order by
    to_number(regexp_substr(productversion, '\d+', 1, 1)),
    to_number(regexp_substr(productversion, '\d+', 1, 2)),
    to_number(regexp_substr(productversion, '\d+', 1, 3))
```

If your version numbers can have more than 3 parts, you can extend the `order by` clause with more `to_number()` expressions.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1b4c7d2650854fc914303889e897feca)**:

```
with t as (
    select '1.0' productversion from dual
    union all select '1.10' from dual
    union all select '10.5.2' from dual
    union all select '16' from dual
    union all select '2.0.0' from dual
)
select * 
from t
order by
    to_number(regexp_substr(productversion, '\d+', 1, 1)),
    to_number(regexp_substr(productversion, '\d+', 1, 2)),
    to_number(regexp_substr(productversion, '\d+', 1, 3))
```

```
| PRODUCTVERSION |
| :------------- |
| 1.0            |
| 1.10           |
| 2.0.0          |
| 10.5.2         |
| 16             |
```

Comment: If it works then accept the answer so that this question is marked as resolved.  You are genious GMB.!!

Answer (score -2):

I would do it like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM KCProductVersion WHERE productid = 1 
ORDER BY
  CASE 
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(value) = 1 THEN CONVERT(INT, value)
  ELSE 999 --or whatever you need 
  END,
  value
```

The first part of the ORDER BY clause takes converts everything to INT with a large number for non-numerics so that they are sorted last.  Then it takes care of sorting the alphabetics at the end.  If you have large amounts of data this may be a chore to run this way